# How to change the @Namednativequery.query dynamic but non-programatically?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

### Presently how it is

```
@Service
 class Impl{

    public ResponseEntity<?> find(patientIdList,shapeNameList){
      someEntity =  repository.findByFilters(patientIdList,shapeNameList);

      return someEntity;
    }


 }
```

---

```
@Entity    
@NamedNativeQuery(      
        name = "MyEntity.findByFilters",
        query = "_________________________________",
        resultSetMapping = "dummyMapping"       
        ))   
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "dummyMapping",
    ...
)
public class ...{
}
```

### USE CASES desired:

when shapeNameList **IS SUPPLIED** by clients rest json input, then @Namednativequery.query mentioned above should be: 
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
query = SELECT DISTINCT a.shape_name as shapename, a.patient_id patientId, a.shape_type_id as shapetypeid  
                        FROM pairdb.tbl_sf_density a 
                        WHERE a.patient_id IN( ?1 )
                        AND a.shapeNameList IN( ?2 )  --this line needs to be dynamically incorporated 
                        group by shapename;
```

when shapeNameList **NOT SUPPLIED** by clients rest json input, then @Namednativequery.query mentioned above should be:
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
query = SELECT DISTINCT a.shape_name as shapename, a.patient_id patientId, a.shape_type_id as shapetypeid 
                        FROM pairdb.tbl_sf_density a 
                        WHERE a.patient_id IN( ?1 )
                        -- AND a.shapeNameList IN( ?2 )  --this line needs to be dynamically omitted from the query within  @NamedNativeQuery above
                        group by shapename;
```

- Specification + QueryDSl/Criteria seems heavy for the purpose.
- As well StringBuilder to cook up the query String also seems JDBC workaround but not proper elegant solution

I'm not being able to build the perfect solution for this dynamic change of the SQL part. Could someone help please with simple Spring JPA solution ?

OR

Can we just manipulate within  the postgres SQL by some logic to switch between
  `'AND a.shapeNameList IN( ?2 ) '`   vs `' '` 
using `COALSCE / NULLIF / IFNULL / CASE WHEN THEN END ? anything ?`

That should be the best option I guess. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specification + QueryDSl/Criteria seems heavy for the purpose.

I don't agree. Since in the comment to Mateusz answer you suggest you have multiple such parameters a `Specification` seems like a perfect fit.

In similar cases, find-by-example works as well, but it doesn't support in-clauses.

If you are willing to consider `@Query` annotations you can use SpEL support write something like this:

```
@Query("... where 0 = ?#{param.size} or a.shapeNameList IN :param")
public Something something(List param);
```

*Typos in the code are not a bug but a training feature.*

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use @NamedNativeQuery, you may as well create who different queries annotated with @NamedNativeQuery and in service decide which one to call depending on data. Service is a right place for any business logic like deciding which query to call.

I would also not put queries in entities, but I would use Repositories instead.

So, the sketch of the solution could be:

```
@Repository
interface ShapesRepository {

    @Query(...)
    List<Shape> findForPatiets(List patientIdList)

    @Query(...)
    List<Shape> findForPatientsAndNameList(List patientIdList, List names)
}

@Service
class ShapesService{
    public find(patientIdList,shapeNameList){
         if (isEmpty(shapeNameList)){
             repository.findForPatients(patientIdList);
         } else {
             repository.findForPatientsAndNameList(patientIdList, shapeNameList);
         }
    }

}
```

But if I were you, I would seriously consider using QueryDSL

Comment: There are multiple such Params( say N params) like names acc. to your example.
In such case as suggested the no of such different queries will grow exponentially as power(2,N).